# Android onNewIntent being called without extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The scenario is a bit complicated to explain but please take time to understand

I'M USING OPTION "DON'T KEEP ACTIVITIES" ON IN THIS SCENARIO

I have activity A that calls a third party sdk Z passing a callback field.

what Z does is irrelevant, but for the sake of explaining it starts few activities in order to collect some data, after the process is finished (with success or error) the callback function is called.

```
SDK_Z.builder("param").build(this, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull String result) {
             ContextCompat.startActivity(context, new Intent(context, ACTIVITY_A.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).putExtra("result", result), null);
             FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("on sucess");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel(@NonNull String cancelMessage) {
             ContextCompat.startActivity(context, new Intent(context, ACTIVITY_A.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).putExtra("result", cancelMessage), null);              
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("on cancel");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull String error) {
             ContextCompat.startActivity(context, new Intent(context, ACTIVITY_A.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).putExtra("result", error), null);              
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("on error");

            }
        });
```

When SDK Z finishes, it finishes all its inner activities, so activity A is on top of stack then there would be no need to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but I just wanted to guarantee

so as i'm using "dont keep activities" at this point, activity A `oncreated` is called [due it be returning to top of stack] later on `onNewIntent` is called

BUT AT NEITHER OF THESE TWO CALLS MY INTENT IS PASSED, the intent i receive never has the "result" param

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    
    if(intent.getStringExtra("result")!=null)
        System.out.println("SUCESS");
}
```

I've debugged so many times, the callback methods are called correctly, activity is recreated, onnewintent is called BUT THE INTENT PARAMETER never has the desired extra

WHY? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: "I'M USING OPTION "DON'T KEEP ACTIVITIES" ON IN THIS SCENARIO" -- if you turn that off, do things work better? If the answer is yes, then perhaps do not use that option here and use other techniques for testing configuration changes (such as actually doing configuration changes).

Comment: @CommonsWare, my app targets low end devices and I assume that during runtime my users will get memory trim all the time, dont keep activities is the easiest way to simulate that

Comment: "Don't keep activities" is completely unrelated to process termination due to low memory conditions. "Don't keep activities" is not a simulation of process termination. At most, it is a simulation of continuous configuration changes. In particular, "don't keep activities" keeps your process around. If you want to simulate process termination, terminate your process using `adb shell am kill your.application.id`.

Comment: And, even if you think that "don't keep activities" is potentially useful, you could still test your scenario from your question without it, and see what happens. If now everything works better, now you know that "don't keep activities" is causing the problem, and you can use that to re-evaluate your use of it.

Comment: Why not just print `intent.getExtras.toString()`?